# MySQL Confusing Query

Tags: php, mysql, yii

While writing a query, 
I am giving `teacher` in where clause and then `coteacher`, on execution, 
It's not displaying any record. And when I reverse the order (1st I write coteacher and then teacher) its listed both records.

There's No indexing on the Column *role_name* and the Table Engine is INNODB.
Why is it ?

```
SELECT *
FROM role
WHERE role.role_name = 'coteacher'
  OR role.role_name = 'teacher'
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25ac3/1

Comment: Please show the exact bit of code that is not working (IE not the working one as above).

Comment: I would try select distinct role_name from role to see what possible values are actually available.  Could it be a case-sensitive issue?

Comment: you need to use `IN` clause rather than the OR / AND Condition

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly get the problem, but do you have tried this :

```
SELECT *
FROM role
WHERE role.role_name IN ('coteacher', 'teacher')
```

?

Comment: Yes! I tried , it's only returning One record Teacher

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with below query :

```html
SELECT * FROM role WHERE (role.role_name = 'coteacher' OR role.role_name = 'teacher')
```

Comment: Your solution is just identical to the query provided by the author... Parentheses are useless here.